# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\left( \cosh x \right) ^{\sin x}-1}{\sinh x\cos \left( \sin \left( x \right) -1 \right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Evaluate the limit
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\left( \cosh x \right) ^{\sin  x}-1}{\sinh x(\cos \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right)-1)}
$$

**My Attempt:** I tried to use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to evalute it, however I found that the $1$st and $2$nd derivative of the numerator is $0$ at $x=0$, and the $3$rd derivative is very complicated. And the method of [Taylor's Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) is too complicated here. So, **my question is**, is there any easier way to evaluate this limit?

The desired answer is $-1$.

Comment: Okay I will edit my claim

Comment: You are right!  They are messy calculations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's handle the denominator first. We can write it as $$x^3\cdot\frac{\sinh x} {x} \cdot \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\cdot \frac {\cos(\sin x) - 1}{\sin^2x}$$ and hence it can be replaced by $-x^3/2$.

To deal with numerator let us write it as $$(\cosh x) ^{\sin x} - 1=\frac{\exp(\sin x\log \cosh x) - 1}{\sin x\log \cosh x} \cdot\frac{\sin x} {x} \cdot\frac {\log\cosh x} {\cosh x - 1}\cdot\frac{\cosh x - 1}{x^2}\cdot x^3$$ and hence it can be replaced by $x^3/2$. It follows that the desired limit is $-1$.

In the above process we have used the following standard limits $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x} {x} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sinh x} {x} =1\\ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\exp(t)-1}{t}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac {\log t} {t-1}=1\\ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac {1-\cos x} {x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\cosh x - 1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Often a little algebra combined with well known/standard limits helps to simplify the expression under limit to a great extent and gives the limit value in direct manner. L'Hospital Rule and Taylor series should be used  when they are damn simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

The first and second derivatives of both numerator and denominator are zero.  The third derivative of the numerator at $x=0$ is $3.$   The third derivative of the denominator at $x=0$ is $-3.$

The limit is $-1.$

Answer (score 1):

> And the method of Taylor's Series is too complicated here.

Not really, actually. Using the Taylor series approximations of $\cos$, $\sin$, $\ln$, $\exp$, and $\cosh$ (all standard) and composing them as we go along:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left( \cosh x \right) ^{\sin  x}-1}{\sinh x(\cos \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right)-1)}
&= \frac{e^{\sin  x \ln \cosh x}-1}{\sinh x(\cos \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right)-1)}
= \frac{e^{(x+o(x)) \ln \left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2\right)}-1}{(x+o(x))(\cos \left( \left( x +o(x) \right)  \right)-1)}\\
&= \frac{e^{(x+o(x)) \left(\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)}-1}{(x+o(x))\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} +o(x^2) \right)}
= \frac{e^{\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3)}-1}{-\frac{x^3}{2} +o(x^3)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3)}{-\frac{x^3}{2} +o(x^3)}
= \frac{1+o(1)}{-1+o(1)} \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} \boxed{-1}
\end{align*}$$